# Single word to refer "Pile of dead bodies"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english

I read this in Google today.

> "Horrific picture shows pile of dead bodies found in migrants' boat | Metro News"

Is there a single word in English to refer to a "pile of dead bodies" .

Comment: One would hope that there is NOT a single word for it.

Comment: The number of English words is finite. The number of possible concepts is infinite. Therefore the probability that any given concept has an assigned English word is almost zero. And our expectations should reflect that probability. We should only expect a concept to have an assigned English words if there’s, a priori, a strong reason to believe one exists. What is your strong reason here to believe such a word exists?

Comment: Is there a single word for it in your native language? Or is this a word you know exists in English but just can't get it off the tip of your tongue? Or are you writing a headline/poem that needs to be shortened?

Comment: @Mitch .. yes in my native language , we will use a single word to refer and we can say it using two three words combined also..  That's why I was so curious to know about it.

Comment: It would help if you have that word in your language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Plenty of options here, all slightly euphemistic: "Mass grave" would probably be the closest, but you have 'Tomb' or 'Boneyard' or 'Charnel' that may all be appropriate.

Comment: *Mass grave* means more of a hole in the ground. *Tomb* and *boneyard* are too tidy

Comment: @chrish I agree; none of them describe a pile of dead bodies quite as succinctly as 'Pile of dead bodies', but OP's looking for an alternative.

Comment: 'charnel' sounds pretty close to a single word for this, except it's more of a small building for a pile of dead bodies than the pile itself.